# How can I set HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath when using Owin?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, configuration, owin

When running my Web ASP solution under Owin, the HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath is null. How can/should I set it such that it represents the physical path of the application within which Owin has been constructed?